# Having a discussion regarding use cases with buddies

Tags: use-case

We're a group of 5 whos in discussion with use cases. I've got my opinion that all of what they have written are use cases, while they do not agree.
So, could you clarify for me if all of these are use cases?

- Log in to a system
- Book a flight
- Pay for a flight
- Search for a flight
- Log out

So, arent these all use cases or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that all of them are use cases.

> In software and systems engineering, a use case is a list of actions
>   or event steps, typically defining the interactions between a role
>   (known in the Unified Modeling Language as an actor) and a system, to
>   achieve a goal.

Maybe you should define the actor or the role, but a part from that I would say that you are right.

For instance, in the next image we can see, a use case diagram, every circle is a use case, similar to the bullets points that he have listed before.

[image]

Obviously, a use case is not defined completly if we don´t enumerate the list of steps or the main success scenario.

Why do your buddies think that they are not use cases?

Comment: I would say it is not, and the way I read your quotation seems to support my understanding of it.. What OP posted are the steps.. which could be used in use case, and, together, they form one. But each of the bullet points is not use case - just the whole list (another one could be just Log in/Search for flight/Log out)

Comment: The bullets points are the goals that the use case wants to achieve, or the use case title.